# Iterate over multiple objects of a generic class with different T but common ancestor

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

### **Class definitions**

I have a generic class restricted to types implementing some interfaces

```
Public Class GenericClass(Of T As {IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2})
    'These are items I want to iterate over
    Public Property Stuff As List(Of T)
End Class
```

Now I have a `MustInherit` class implementing said interfaces

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Implements IMyInterface1
    Implements IMyInterface2

    Public Sub DoSomething()
       'This is a method I want to call while iterating
    End Sub
End Class
```

and some child classes of this base class

```
Public Class ChildClass1
    Inherits BaseClass
End Class
Public Class ChildClass2
    Inherits BaseClass
End Class
```

Now I create some objects

```
Dim Item1 As New GenericClass(Of ChildClass1)
Dim Item2 As New GenericClass(Of ChildClass2)
```

### **What I want to do**

Let's recap: `Item1` and `Item2` both contain a list of `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2` respectively. Each member of these lists has the `DoSomething` method inherited from `BaseClass`.

I would like to call `DoSomething()` for any member of each of those lists.

### **What I tried**

I can, of course, iterate over the lists in each `ItemX` individually. But since I have more than two of those in the actual program this is very messy.

I can not think of a way to combine Item1 and Item2 into a list to iterate over. I can't use

```
Dim Items As New List(Of GenericClass(Of BaseClass))
Items.Add(Item1)
Items.Add(Item2)
For Each Item As GenericClass(Of BaseClass) In Items
    For Each SubItem As BaseClass In Item.Stuff
        SubItem.DoSomething()
    Next
Next
```

which gives the design-time error:

> BC30311    Value of type 'GenericClass(Of ChildClass1)' cannot be converted to 'GenericClass(Of BaseClass)'

at the 2nd line.

### **Finally**

Is there any way I can solve this dilemma instead of skipping the outer loop in the above example and writing the same code for each of the `ItemX`?

As far as I can tell it wouldn't make a difference if I restricted the `GenericClass` to `BaseClass`, would it?

Comment: Your `GenericClass` is getting in the way.  `DoSomething` is defined on the  BaseClass, but that method is not part of either interface used in the constraint.  Try changing it to `MustOverride` to start, but since it is not part of either interface, it still wont be available.  `GenericClass` needs to be changed, but I am not sure what you are really after

Comment: `DoSomething` is specific to the `BaseClass` functionality unfortunately, but the `GenericClass` needs to be of wider scope as it is used for other things elsewhere. I understand that the logic behind it can be hard to see, but it is there ;-)

Comment: But you cant constrain the objects created to `IMyInterface1` and `IMyInterface2` and still use BaseClass methods.  You are creating one Type and trying to use it as another.  Since there is no relation between the interfaces and base class, you cant even cast them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can solve this dilemma instead of skipping the outer loop in the above example and writing the same code for each of the ItemX?

Change `GenericClass` to implement the following interface:

```
Interface IGenericClass(Of Out T As {IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2})
    ReadOnly Property Stuff As IEnumerable(Of T)
End Interface
```

Now you can iterate over all items and stuff:

```
Dim Items As IEnumerable(Of IGenericClass(Of BaseClass)) = {
    New GenericClass(Of ChildClass1), New GenericClass(Of ChildClass2)}

For Each Item In Items
    For Each SubItem In Item.Stuff
        SubItem.DoSomething()
    Next
Next
```